# jQuery find table rows but ignore rows in child tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to alternate row background-images of a table...

```
$("table:not([class])").each(function () {
    $(this).find("tbody tr:even td").css({
        "background-image": "url(/images/rowBg1.png)"
    });
    $(this).find("tbody tr:odd td").css({
        "background-image": "url(/images/rowBg2.png)"
    });
});
```

This works fine most of the time, but if I have a situation where there is a child table in one of the cells and it's carrying on selecting those rows.

I need it to only select the rows in the table in the each function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Give an ID to your outer table, say, `id="outer"` and then add it to the main selector: `$("table#outer:not([class])")...`

Comment: I need this to work on multiple tables on a single page so that's not practical. I just need it to not apply the function to child tables

Comment: any fiddle? i would advice the use of `tbody > tr` selector at first glance

Comment: You could do the same with classes, not necessarily IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the immediate child selector:

```
table > tbody > tr
```

See more here http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KLKwX/

Comment: I don't have your full HTML but I just added an example of how I would solve it.

Comment: Any way I can get your fiddle working using the each function in my code? http://jsfiddle.net/KLKwX/1/ (non working fiddle based on @Ian's feedback

Comment: Check it out now. It is not the most elegant solution but works: http://jsfiddle.net/KLKwX/2/ using the `children()` function.

Comment: OK... got there eventually kind of based on your answer... 
`$(this).find("> tfoot tr td").css({`
Thanks

Comment: @Tom Yeah I must've been mistaken. I thought you could traverse down the tree with the selector passed to `.children()` like you can with `.find()`, but it looks like you can only go one level. ced-b's last comment is what I came up with too. I'm going to delete my first comment